# Parsing Locally Registered SQL Server names XML file using Vb .Net

Tags: sql-server, xml, vb.net

I need to retrieve names of the locally registered MS SQL Servers that get stored in a XML file. This is usually located at "C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell\RegSrvr.xml"

Once retrieved, I need to populate these in a combobox. I am using below code. But could not figure out which tag to use from this xml for the "m_xmld.SelectNodes" code. Any advise is appreciated.

```
 If System.IO.File.Exists(RegSrvrFile) Then
                Dim m_xmld As XmlDocument
                Dim m_nodelist As XmlNodeList
                Dim m_node As XmlNode
                'Create the XML Document
                m_xmld = New XmlDocument()
                'Load the Xml file
                m_xmld.Load(RegSrvrFile)
                'Get the list of name nodes 
                m_nodelist = m_xmld.SelectNodes("/model/instances/document/data/RegisteredServers")
            End If
        End If
```

Sample XML is attached.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<model xmlns="http://schemas.serviceml.org/smlif/2007/02">
  <identity>
    <name>urn:uuid:96fe1236-abf6-4a57-b54d-e9baab394fd1</name>
    <baseURI>http://documentcollection/</baseURI>
  </identity>
  <xs:bufferSchema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <definitions xmlns:sfc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08">
      <document>
        <docinfo>
          <aliases>
            <alias>/system/schema/RegisteredServers</alias>
          </aliases>
          <sfc:version DomainVersion="1" />
        </docinfo>
        <data>
          <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/RegisteredServers/2007/08" xmlns:sfc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08" xmlns:sml="http://schemas.serviceml.org/sml/2007/02" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
            <xs:element name="RegisteredServersStore">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:any namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/RegisteredServers/2007/08" processContents="skip" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="ServerGroup">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:any namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/RegisteredServers/2007/08" processContents="skip" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="RegisteredServer">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:any namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/RegisteredServers/2007/08" processContents="skip" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <RegisteredServers:bufferData xmlns:RegisteredServers="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/RegisteredServers/2007/08">
              <instances xmlns:sfc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08">
                <document>
                  <docinfo>
                    <aliases>
                      <alias>/RegisteredServersStore</alias>
                    </aliases>
                    <sfc:version DomainVersion="1" />
                  </docinfo>
                  <data>
                    <RegisteredServers:RegisteredServersStore xmlns:RegisteredServers="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/RegisteredServers/2007/08" xmlns:sfc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08" xmlns:sml="http://schemas.serviceml.org/sml/2007/02" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                      <RegisteredServers:ServerGroups>
                        <sfc:Collection>
                          <sfc:Reference sml:ref="true">
                            <sml:Uri>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/AnalysisServicesServerGroup</sml:Uri>
                          </sfc:Reference>
                          <sfc:Reference sml:ref="true">
                            <sml:Uri>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/CentralManagementServerGroup</sml:Uri>
                          </sfc:Reference>
                          <sfc:Reference sml:ref="true">
                            <sml:Uri>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/DatabaseEngineServerGroup</sml:Uri>
                          </sfc:Reference>
                          <sfc:Reference sml:ref="true">
                            <sml:Uri>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/IntegrationServicesServerGroup</sml:Uri>
                          </sfc:Reference>
                          <sfc:Reference sml:ref="true">
                            <sml:Uri>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/ReportingServicesServerGroup</sml:Uri>
                          </sfc:Reference>
                          <sfc:Reference sml:ref="true">
                            <sml:Uri>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/SqlServerCompactEditionServerGroup</sml:Uri>
                          </sfc:Reference>
                        </sfc:Collection>
                      </RegisteredServers:ServerGroups>
                    </RegisteredServers:RegisteredServersStore>
                  </data>
                </document>
                <document>
                  <docinfo>
                    <aliases>
                      <alias>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/AnalysisServicesServerGroup</alias>
                    </aliases>
                    <sfc:version DomainVersion="1" />
                  </docinfo>
                  <data>
                    <RegisteredServers:ServerGroup xmlns:RegisteredServers="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/RegisteredServers/2007/08" xmlns:sfc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08" xmlns:sml="http://schemas.serviceml.org/sml/2007/02" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                      <RegisteredServers:Parent>
                        <sfc:Reference sml:ref="true">
                          <sml:Uri>/RegisteredServersStore</sml:Uri>
                        </sfc:Reference>
                      </RegisteredServers:Parent>
                      <RegisteredServers:Name type="string">AnalysisServicesServerGroup</RegisteredServers:Name>
                      <RegisteredServers:ServerType type="ServerType">AnalysisServices</RegisteredServers:ServerType>
                    </RegisteredServers:ServerGroup>
                  </data>
                </document>
                <document>
                  <docinfo>
                    <aliases>
                      <alias>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/CentralManagementServerGroup</alias>
                    </aliases>
                    <sfc:version DomainVersion="1" />
                  </docinfo>
                  <data>
                    <RegisteredServers:ServerGroup xmlns:RegisteredServers="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/RegisteredServers/2007/08" xmlns:sfc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08" xmlns:sml="http://schemas.serviceml.org/sml/2007/02" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                      <RegisteredServers:Parent>
                        <sfc:Reference sml:ref="true">
                          <sml:Uri>/RegisteredServersStore</sml:Uri>
                        </sfc:Reference>
                      </RegisteredServers:Parent>
                      <RegisteredServers:Name type="string">CentralManagementServerGroup</RegisteredServers:Name>
                      <RegisteredServers:ServerType type="ServerType">DatabaseEngine</RegisteredServers:ServerType>
                    </RegisteredServers:ServerGroup>
                  </data>
                </document>
                <document>
                  <docinfo>
                    <aliases>
                      <alias>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/DatabaseEngineServerGroup</alias>
                    </aliases>
                    <sfc:version DomainVersion="1" />
                  </docinfo>
                  <data>
                    <RegisteredServers:ServerGroup xmlns:RegisteredServers="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/RegisteredServers/2007/08" xmlns:sfc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08" xmlns:sml="http://schemas.serviceml.org/sml/2007/02" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                      <RegisteredServers:RegisteredServers>
                        <sfc:Collection>
                          <sfc:Reference sml:ref="true">
                            <sml:Uri>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/DatabaseEngineServerGroup/RegisteredServer/MYSQLSERVER\DBInstance</sml:Uri>
                          </sfc:Reference>
                        </sfc:Collection>
                      </RegisteredServers:RegisteredServers>
                      <RegisteredServers:Parent>
                        <sfc:Reference sml:ref="true">
                          <sml:Uri>/RegisteredServersStore</sml:Uri>
                        </sfc:Reference>
                      </RegisteredServers:Parent>
                      <RegisteredServers:Name type="string">DatabaseEngineServerGroup</RegisteredServers:Name>
                      <RegisteredServers:ServerType type="ServerType">DatabaseEngine</RegisteredServers:ServerType>
                    </RegisteredServers:ServerGroup>
                  </data>
                </document>
                <document>
                  <docinfo>
                    <aliases>
                      <alias>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/DatabaseEngineServerGroup/RegisteredServer/MYSQLSERVER\DBInstance</alias>
                    </aliases>
                    <sfc:version DomainVersion="1" />
                  </docinfo>
                  <data>
                    <RegisteredServers:RegisteredServer xmlns:RegisteredServers="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/RegisteredServers/2007/08" xmlns:sfc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08" xmlns:sml="http://schemas.serviceml.org/sml/2007/02" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                      <RegisteredServers:Parent>
                        <sfc:Reference sml:ref="true">
                          <sml:Uri>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/DatabaseEngineServerGroup</sml:Uri>
                        </sfc:Reference>
                      </RegisteredServers:Parent>
                      <RegisteredServers:Name type="string">MYSQLSERVER\DBInstance</RegisteredServers:Name>
                      <RegisteredServers:ServerName type="string">MYSQLSERVER\DBInstance</RegisteredServers:ServerName>
                      <RegisteredServers:UseCustomConnectionColor type="boolean">false</RegisteredServers:UseCustomConnectionColor>
                      <RegisteredServers:CustomConnectionColorArgb type="int">0</RegisteredServers:CustomConnectionColorArgb>
                      <RegisteredServers:ServerType type="ServerType">DatabaseEngine</RegisteredServers:ServerType>
                      <RegisteredServers:ConnectionStringWithEncryptedPassword type="string">data source=MYSQLSERVER\DBInstance;integrated security=True;pooling=False;multipleactiveresultsets=False</RegisteredServers:ConnectionStringWithEncryptedPassword>
                      <RegisteredServers:CredentialPersistenceType type="CredentialPersistenceType">PersistLoginName</RegisteredServers:CredentialPersistenceType>
                    </RegisteredServers:RegisteredServer>
                  </data>
                </document>
                <document>
                  <docinfo>
                    <aliases>
                      <alias>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/IntegrationServicesServerGroup</alias>
                    </aliases>
                    <sfc:version DomainVersion="1" />
                  </docinfo>
                  <data>
                    <RegisteredServers:ServerGroup xmlns:RegisteredServers="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/RegisteredServers/2007/08" xmlns:sfc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08" xmlns:sml="http://schemas.serviceml.org/sml/2007/02" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                      <RegisteredServers:RegisteredServers>
                        <sfc:Collection>
                          <sfc:Reference sml:ref="true">
                            <sml:Uri>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/IntegrationServicesServerGroup/RegisteredServer/MYSQLSERVER</sml:Uri>
                          </sfc:Reference>
                        </sfc:Collection>
                      </RegisteredServers:RegisteredServers>
                      <RegisteredServers:Parent>
                        <sfc:Reference sml:ref="true">
                          <sml:Uri>/RegisteredServersStore</sml:Uri>
                        </sfc:Reference>
                      </RegisteredServers:Parent>
                      <RegisteredServers:Name type="string">IntegrationServicesServerGroup</RegisteredServers:Name>
                      <RegisteredServers:ServerType type="ServerType">IntegrationServices</RegisteredServers:ServerType>
                    </RegisteredServers:ServerGroup>
                  </data>
                </document>
                <document>
                  <docinfo>
                    <aliases>
                      <alias>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/IntegrationServicesServerGroup/RegisteredServer/MYSQLSERVER</alias>
                    </aliases>
                    <sfc:version DomainVersion="1" />
                  </docinfo>
                  <data>
                    <RegisteredServers:RegisteredServer xmlns:RegisteredServers="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/RegisteredServers/2007/08" xmlns:sfc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08" xmlns:sml="http://schemas.serviceml.org/sml/2007/02" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                      <RegisteredServers:Parent>
                        <sfc:Reference sml:ref="true">
                          <sml:Uri>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/IntegrationServicesServerGroup</sml:Uri>
                        </sfc:Reference>
                      </RegisteredServers:Parent>
                      <RegisteredServers:Name type="string">MYSQLSERVER</RegisteredServers:Name>
                      <RegisteredServers:ServerName type="string">MYSQLSERVER</RegisteredServers:ServerName>
                      <RegisteredServers:UseCustomConnectionColor type="boolean">false</RegisteredServers:UseCustomConnectionColor>
                      <RegisteredServers:CustomConnectionColorArgb type="int">0</RegisteredServers:CustomConnectionColorArgb>
                      <RegisteredServers:ServerType type="ServerType">IntegrationServices</RegisteredServers:ServerType>
                      <RegisteredServers:ConnectionStringWithEncryptedPassword type="string">server=MYSQLSERVER</RegisteredServers:ConnectionStringWithEncryptedPassword>
                      <RegisteredServers:CredentialPersistenceType type="CredentialPersistenceType">PersistLoginName</RegisteredServers:CredentialPersistenceType>
                    </RegisteredServers:RegisteredServer>
                  </data>
                </document>
                <document>
                  <docinfo>
                    <aliases>
                      <alias>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/ReportingServicesServerGroup</alias>
                    </aliases>
                    <sfc:version DomainVersion="1" />
                  </docinfo>
                  <data>
                    <RegisteredServers:ServerGroup xmlns:RegisteredServers="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/RegisteredServers/2007/08" xmlns:sfc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08" xmlns:sml="http://schemas.serviceml.org/sml/2007/02" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                      <RegisteredServers:Parent>
                        <sfc:Reference sml:ref="true">
                          <sml:Uri>/RegisteredServersStore</sml:Uri>
                        </sfc:Reference>
                      </RegisteredServers:Parent>
                      <RegisteredServers:Name type="string">ReportingServicesServerGroup</RegisteredServers:Name>
                      <RegisteredServers:ServerType type="ServerType">ReportingServices</RegisteredServers:ServerType>
                    </RegisteredServers:ServerGroup>
                  </data>
                </document>
                <document>
                  <docinfo>
                    <aliases>
                      <alias>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/SqlServerCompactEditionServerGroup</alias>
                    </aliases>
                    <sfc:version DomainVersion="1" />
                  </docinfo>
                  <data>
                    <RegisteredServers:ServerGroup xmlns:RegisteredServers="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/RegisteredServers/2007/08" xmlns:sfc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08" xmlns:sml="http://schemas.serviceml.org/sml/2007/02" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                      <RegisteredServers:Parent>
                        <sfc:Reference sml:ref="true">
                          <sml:Uri>/RegisteredServersStore</sml:Uri>
                        </sfc:Reference>
                      </RegisteredServers:Parent>
                      <RegisteredServers:Name type="string">SqlServerCompactEditionServerGroup</RegisteredServers:Name>
                      <RegisteredServers:ServerType type="ServerType">SqlServerCompactEdition</RegisteredServers:ServerType>
                    </RegisteredServers:ServerGroup>
                  </data>
                </document>
              </instances>
            </RegisteredServers:bufferData>
          </xs:schema>
        </data>
      </document>
    </definitions>
  </xs:bufferSchema>
</model>
```

Comment: Do you have a sample of the XML?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the SqlDataSourceEnumerator.GetDataSources method https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sql.sqldatasourceenumerator.getdatasources(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You're very likely missing namespaces in your XPath query. Also, you'd probably be better off using @PaulHunt's suggestion, since your method will vary from SQL Server version to SQL Server version

Comment: Hi Paul, I tired SqlDataSourceEnumerator.GetDataSource method but it gives my local and one other instance only. We manually register SQL Server instances on the local machine. I noticed that on first registration the RegSrvr.xml gets created and then updated for subsequent additions. This server names are then populated by an utility which we use to load data in a Main application database.

Comment: Hi Dan, Let me try and see if I can post this XML here..its a about  400-500 rows so not sure I can paste it as whole..

Comment: Hi @DanField Field, I have added the XML sample above..Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is missing namespaces, and doesn't seem to actually point to a node.  Try something like this:

```
Dim xml As String = "<?xml version=""1.0""?><model xmlns=""http://schemas.serviceml.org/smlif/2007/02""><identity><name>urn:uuid:96fe1236-abf6-4a57-b54d-e9baab394fd1</name><baseURI>http://documentcollection/</baseURI></identity><xs:bufferSchema xmlns:xs=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema""><definitions xmlns:sfc=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08""><document><docinfo><aliases><alias>/system/schema/RegisteredServers</alias></aliases><sfc:version DomainVersion=""1"" /></docinfo><data><xs:schema targetNamespace=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/RegisteredServers/2007/08"" xmlns:sfc=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08"" xmlns:sml=""http://schemas.serviceml.org/sml/2007/02"" xmlns:xs=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" elementFormDefault=""qualified""><xs:element name=""RegisteredServersStore""><xs:complexType><xs:sequence><xs:any namespace=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/RegisteredServers/2007/08"" processContents=""skip"" minOccurs=""0"" maxOccurs=""unbounded"" /></xs:sequence></xs:complexType></xs:element><xs:element name=""ServerGroup""><xs:complexType><xs:sequence><xs:any namespace=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/RegisteredServers/2007/08"" processContents=""skip"" minOccurs=""0"" maxOccurs=""unbounded"" /></xs:sequence></xs:complexType></xs:element><xs:element name=""RegisteredServer""><xs:complexType><xs:sequence><xs:any namespace=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/RegisteredServers/2007/08"" processContents=""skip"" minOccurs=""0"" maxOccurs=""unbounded"" /></xs:sequence></xs:complexType></xs:element><RegisteredServers:bufferData xmlns:RegisteredServers=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/RegisteredServers/2007/08""><instances xmlns:sfc=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08""><document><docinfo><aliases><alias>/RegisteredServersStore</alias></aliases><sfc:version DomainVersion=""1"" /></docinfo><data><RegisteredServers:RegisteredServersStore xmlns:RegisteredServers=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/RegisteredServers/2007/08"" xmlns:sfc=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08"" xmlns:sml=""http://schemas.serviceml.org/sml/2007/02"" xmlns:xs=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema""><RegisteredServers:ServerGroups><sfc:Collection><sfc:Reference sml:ref=""true""><sml:Uri>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/AnalysisServicesServerGroup</sml:Uri></sfc:Reference><sfc:Reference sml:ref=""true""><sml:Uri>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/CentralManagementServerGroup</sml:Uri></sfc:Reference><sfc:Reference sml:ref=""true""><sml:Uri>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/DatabaseEngineServerGroup</sml:Uri></sfc:Reference><sfc:Reference sml:ref=""true""><sml:Uri>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/IntegrationServicesServerGroup</sml:Uri></sfc:Reference><sfc:Reference sml:ref=""true""><sml:Uri>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/ReportingServicesServerGroup</sml:Uri></sfc:Reference><sfc:Reference sml:ref=""true""><sml:Uri>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/SqlServerCompactEditionServerGroup</sml:Uri></sfc:Reference></sfc:Collection></RegisteredServers:ServerGroups></RegisteredServers:RegisteredServersStore></data></document><document><docinfo><aliases><alias>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/AnalysisServicesServerGroup</alias></aliases><sfc:version DomainVersion=""1"" /></docinfo><data><RegisteredServers:ServerGroup xmlns:RegisteredServers=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/RegisteredServers/2007/08"" xmlns:sfc=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08"" xmlns:sml=""http://schemas.serviceml.org/sml/2007/02"" xmlns:xs=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema""><RegisteredServers:Parent><sfc:Reference sml:ref=""true""><sml:Uri>/RegisteredServersStore</sml:Uri></sfc:Reference></RegisteredServers:Parent><RegisteredServers:Name type=""string"">AnalysisServicesServerGroup</RegisteredServers:Name><RegisteredServers:ServerType type=""ServerType"">AnalysisServices</RegisteredServers:ServerType></RegisteredServers:ServerGroup></data></document><document><docinfo><aliases><alias>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/CentralManagementServerGroup</alias></aliases><sfc:version DomainVersion=""1"" /></docinfo><data><RegisteredServers:ServerGroup xmlns:RegisteredServers=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/RegisteredServers/2007/08"" xmlns:sfc=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08"" xmlns:sml=""http://schemas.serviceml.org/sml/2007/02"" xmlns:xs=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema""><RegisteredServers:Parent><sfc:Reference sml:ref=""true""><sml:Uri>/RegisteredServersStore</sml:Uri></sfc:Reference></RegisteredServers:Parent><RegisteredServers:Name type=""string"">CentralManagementServerGroup</RegisteredServers:Name><RegisteredServers:ServerType type=""ServerType"">DatabaseEngine</RegisteredServers:ServerType></RegisteredServers:ServerGroup></data></document><document><docinfo><aliases><alias>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/DatabaseEngineServerGroup</alias></aliases><sfc:version DomainVersion=""1"" /></docinfo><data><RegisteredServers:ServerGroup xmlns:RegisteredServers=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/RegisteredServers/2007/08"" xmlns:sfc=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08"" xmlns:sml=""http://schemas.serviceml.org/sml/2007/02"" xmlns:xs=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema""><RegisteredServers:RegisteredServers><sfc:Collection><sfc:Reference sml:ref=""true""><sml:Uri>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/DatabaseEngineServerGroup/RegisteredServer/MYSQLSERVER\DBInstance</sml:Uri></sfc:Reference></sfc:Collection></RegisteredServers:RegisteredServers><RegisteredServers:Parent><sfc:Reference sml:ref=""true""><sml:Uri>/RegisteredServersStore</sml:Uri></sfc:Reference></RegisteredServers:Parent><RegisteredServers:Name type=""string"">DatabaseEngineServerGroup</RegisteredServers:Name><RegisteredServers:ServerType type=""ServerType"">DatabaseEngine</RegisteredServers:ServerType></RegisteredServers:ServerGroup></data></document><document><docinfo><aliases><alias>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/DatabaseEngineServerGroup/RegisteredServer/MYSQLSERVER\DBInstance</alias></aliases><sfc:version DomainVersion=""1"" /></docinfo><data><RegisteredServers:RegisteredServer xmlns:RegisteredServers=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/RegisteredServers/2007/08"" xmlns:sfc=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08"" xmlns:sml=""http://schemas.serviceml.org/sml/2007/02"" xmlns:xs=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema""><RegisteredServers:Parent><sfc:Reference sml:ref=""true""><sml:Uri>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/DatabaseEngineServerGroup</sml:Uri></sfc:Reference></RegisteredServers:Parent><RegisteredServers:Name type=""string"">MYSQLSERVER\DBInstance</RegisteredServers:Name><RegisteredServers:ServerName type=""string"">MYSQLSERVER\DBInstance</RegisteredServers:ServerName><RegisteredServers:UseCustomConnectionColor type=""boolean"">false</RegisteredServers:UseCustomConnectionColor><RegisteredServers:CustomConnectionColorArgb type=""int"">0</RegisteredServers:CustomConnectionColorArgb><RegisteredServers:ServerType type=""ServerType"">DatabaseEngine</RegisteredServers:ServerType><RegisteredServers:ConnectionStringWithEncryptedPassword type=""string"">data source=MYSQLSERVER\DBInstance;integrated security=True;pooling=False;multipleactiveresultsets=False</RegisteredServers:ConnectionStringWithEncryptedPassword><RegisteredServers:CredentialPersistenceType type=""CredentialPersistenceType"">PersistLoginName</RegisteredServers:CredentialPersistenceType></RegisteredServers:RegisteredServer></data></document><document><docinfo><aliases><alias>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/IntegrationServicesServerGroup</alias></aliases><sfc:version DomainVersion=""1"" /></docinfo><data><RegisteredServers:ServerGroup xmlns:RegisteredServers=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/RegisteredServers/2007/08"" xmlns:sfc=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08"" xmlns:sml=""http://schemas.serviceml.org/sml/2007/02"" xmlns:xs=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema""><RegisteredServers:RegisteredServers><sfc:Collection><sfc:Reference sml:ref=""true""><sml:Uri>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/IntegrationServicesServerGroup/RegisteredServer/MYSQLSERVER</sml:Uri></sfc:Reference></sfc:Collection></RegisteredServers:RegisteredServers><RegisteredServers:Parent><sfc:Reference sml:ref=""true""><sml:Uri>/RegisteredServersStore</sml:Uri></sfc:Reference></RegisteredServers:Parent><RegisteredServers:Name type=""string"">IntegrationServicesServerGroup</RegisteredServers:Name><RegisteredServers:ServerType type=""ServerType"">IntegrationServices</RegisteredServers:ServerType></RegisteredServers:ServerGroup></data></document><document><docinfo><aliases><alias>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/IntegrationServicesServerGroup/RegisteredServer/MYSQLSERVER</alias></aliases><sfc:version DomainVersion=""1"" /></docinfo><data><RegisteredServers:RegisteredServer xmlns:RegisteredServers=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/RegisteredServers/2007/08"" xmlns:sfc=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08"" xmlns:sml=""http://schemas.serviceml.org/sml/2007/02"" xmlns:xs=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema""><RegisteredServers:Parent><sfc:Reference sml:ref=""true""><sml:Uri>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/IntegrationServicesServerGroup</sml:Uri></sfc:Reference></RegisteredServers:Parent><RegisteredServers:Name type=""string"">MYSQLSERVER</RegisteredServers:Name><RegisteredServers:ServerName type=""string"">MYSQLSERVER</RegisteredServers:ServerName><RegisteredServers:UseCustomConnectionColor type=""boolean"">false</RegisteredServers:UseCustomConnectionColor><RegisteredServers:CustomConnectionColorArgb type=""int"">0</RegisteredServers:CustomConnectionColorArgb><RegisteredServers:ServerType type=""ServerType"">IntegrationServices</RegisteredServers:ServerType><RegisteredServers:ConnectionStringWithEncryptedPassword type=""string"">server=MYSQLSERVER</RegisteredServers:ConnectionStringWithEncryptedPassword><RegisteredServers:CredentialPersistenceType type=""CredentialPersistenceType"">PersistLoginName</RegisteredServers:CredentialPersistenceType></RegisteredServers:RegisteredServer></data></document><document><docinfo><aliases><alias>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/ReportingServicesServerGroup</alias></aliases><sfc:version DomainVersion=""1"" /></docinfo><data><RegisteredServers:ServerGroup xmlns:RegisteredServers=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/RegisteredServers/2007/08"" xmlns:sfc=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08"" xmlns:sml=""http://schemas.serviceml.org/sml/2007/02"" xmlns:xs=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema""><RegisteredServers:Parent><sfc:Reference sml:ref=""true""><sml:Uri>/RegisteredServersStore</sml:Uri></sfc:Reference></RegisteredServers:Parent><RegisteredServers:Name type=""string"">ReportingServicesServerGroup</RegisteredServers:Name><RegisteredServers:ServerType type=""ServerType"">ReportingServices</RegisteredServers:ServerType></RegisteredServers:ServerGroup></data></document><document><docinfo><aliases><alias>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/SqlServerCompactEditionServerGroup</alias></aliases><sfc:version DomainVersion=""1"" /></docinfo><data><RegisteredServers:ServerGroup xmlns:RegisteredServers=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/RegisteredServers/2007/08"" xmlns:sfc=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08"" xmlns:sml=""http://schemas.serviceml.org/sml/2007/02"" xmlns:xs=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema""><RegisteredServers:Parent><sfc:Reference sml:ref=""true""><sml:Uri>/RegisteredServersStore</sml:Uri></sfc:Reference></RegisteredServers:Parent><RegisteredServers:Name type=""string"">SqlServerCompactEditionServerGroup</RegisteredServers:Name><RegisteredServers:ServerType type=""ServerType"">SqlServerCompactEdition</RegisteredServers:ServerType></RegisteredServers:ServerGroup></data></document></instances></RegisteredServers:bufferData></xs:schema></data></document></definitions></xs:bufferSchema></model>"

Dim m_xmld As XmlDocument


Dim m_nodelist As XmlNodeList
Dim m_node As XmlNode
'Create the XML Document
m_xmld = New XmlDocument()
'Load the Xml file
m_xmld.LoadXml(xml)

Dim m_xmlnsmgr As XmlNamespaceManager
m_xmlnsmgr = New XmlNamespaceManager(m_xmld.NameTable)
m_xmlnsmgr.AddNamespace("rs", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/RegisteredServers/2007/08")
m_xmlnsmgr.AddNamespace("sfc", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08")
m_xmlnsmgr.AddNamespace("sml", "http://schemas.serviceml.org/sml/2007/02")
'Get the list of name nodes 
m_nodelist = m_xmld.SelectNodes("//rs:RegisteredServer", m_xmlnsmgr)

For Each el In m_nodelist

    Console.WriteLine(el.SelectSingleNode("rs:ServerName", m_xmlnsmgr).InnerText)
Next
Console.ReadKey()
```

This will select all `RegisteredServer` nodes in the "RegisteredServers" namespace, and then loop through them to get the `ServerName` node in the same namespace.

Comment: Hi @Dan Field, you my friend are a true star... It worked like magic..
I was getting an exception but I commented it Console.ReadKey(). 
Also, changed teh first line from your code. Dim xml As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(RegSrvrFile) .. Many thanks again

Comment: Glad to help.  The console bits were just from a testing harness I had set up - the main idea here is how to properly use the namespaces.